# Create Microsoft Word 2016 template from scratch

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016, templates

I would like to create a complete word template from scratch but so far I have only found scattered resources.
I used to work in a company that had their template(s) set up including a custom ribbon.

I'd like to understand the proper use of:

- Styles, derived or liked etc.
- the 'Organizer' for word templates
- Designs / Themes including the selection of Colours and default fonts

  - How do I save theme settings across the office products into the same Theme?
- the role of *Building Blocks.dotx* and *Built-In Building Blocks.dotx*

  - apparently this is where Table of Content etc styles/designs are defined?
- how to distribute it using the Workgroups template folder option
- set-up of custom properties
- non-printable text for explanation or guidance
- Styles to set-up

  - cover page
  - numbered headings
  - image and table numbering
  - header and footer
  - Index, TOC, list of figures (image/tables)
  - tables
- general Do's and Don'ts would also be nice

I'm not looking for instructions how to copy a doc to dot file or perform a Save-As.

So far I've found some scattered useful tips [here](https://wordribbon.tips.net/C0689_Templates.html), [here](https://www.lifewire.com/create-and-use-word-templates-3539889) and elsewhere, however this is often too much fluff. Where can I find the (Microsoft?) resources getting to the nuts and bolts that explain how it should be done?

Comment: Go to ShaunaKelly.com (https://shaunakelly.com/)  and read everything. Take it to heart. Especially the sections on heading and numbering.

Comment: @Ring Thank I had a look around there plenty of good stuff. Unfortunately Shauna has passed away and newer 'features' are thus not covered.

Comment: Yeah. That was my reaction, too. I never met of traded any emails with her or anything, but I've certainly benefited by her legacy to us. It is unfortunate that the site is only archived. She must have written some awesome documentation, though. Most of the information still applies, in any event. MS still treats word as something that office admins use to write memos and send mail-merge letters and not something that writers use to create real documentation. That's one reason you'll find so many of the serious tech writing positions using a better writing tool (e.g., FrameMaker, Flare, etc.)